# Need help to create Wordpress page that decodes a text file and publishes it in JSON format

Tags: php, json

I would like to create a Wordpress page that lists temperature and humidity data.  The data originates in an encoded .txt file. I'm using the following PHP file to decode the data in the text file.
I haven't been successful at creating a functional page in Wordpress using this code.

The .txt file is also reproduced below.

```
<?php
// publish_payload_in_json.php
// Remote Home Monitor with Hologram Nova
// Publish JSON payload
// Decodes Hologram payload and publishes it in JSON format. JSON data is
// later loaded by the Remote Home Monitor dashboard with JQuery.
//
// Luis Ortiz - luislab.com
// January 5, 2018

$whFileName = "./payload.txt";   // Home Monitor payload

if ( is_readable($whFileName) ) {             // better than file_exists()
    $whFileHandle = fopen($whFileName, 'r') or die("1815");

    $data = trim(fgets($whFileHandle));
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    fclose($whFileHandle);

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $data;
    }else {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
        header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
    }
}
```

?>

Payload.txt

```
eyJ0ZW1wZXJhdHVyZSI6IDY3LjQ2MDAwMTM3MzI5MTAyLCAiaHVtaWRpdHkiOiA0OC45MDAwMDE1MjU4Nzg5MDZ9
5x.20x.5x.21x
HologramCloud (https://hologram.io)
webhookkeyxxxxxx
```

Comment: What about fetching data directly from the HologramCloud RESTAPI to display on site?

Comment: Thanks much for the reply @birgire.  Do you have an example or suggestion for a guide to teach me how to do this in Wordpress?

Comment: It's possible to create a json response in WP, e.g. via custom rest route, but I wonder if the middle host (WP) is needed, i.e. just fetch the json directly from the Hologram REST API (if available)? I've not used the Hologram service, but maybe [this](https://hologram.io/docs/reference/cloud/http/) or  [this](https://help.hologram.io/managing-your-account/using-holograms-rest-api-a-guide-for-beginners) can help?